# Data Formatting in Microsoft Excel: Cell formatting, Text formatting, and Number Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

1. Formatting text or numbers can make them appear more visible especially when you have a large worksheet.
2. Formatting in Excel is a simple process of modifying or manipulating data in spreadsheets from one form to another. Formatting can be done based on appearance and data types.
3. In Excel, the whole entered data in the sheet uses the same formatting by default which can make the data look monotonous, dull, and difficult to read. Excel provides a pool of tools called formatting tools which customize the data in such a way that it only affects the appearance of the data and not the content.

These are the varieties of definitions one would find if he/she were to search what Data Formatting is. In the past 5 days, I have read countless articles to understand what data formatting is, why there's a need for data formatting, and why there's no standard definition for it. If I make my part clear, can anyone please explain this to me so I could be relieved "mentally"?

P.S. I have received numerous explanations for this doubt from SuperUsers, but I still have a question. Can define just format for me, not data or cell formatting, but just formatting? I have read countless definitions and it goes like this: Format means the general arrangement, plan, or design, etc., of sth. So, are date, time, currency, and percentage formats different designs/visuals of numerical data? Are these (currency symbols, percentages, dates, time stamps) really just visuals?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer this question

> Can define just format for me, not data or cell formatting, but just formatting? I have read countless definitions and it goes like this: Format means the general arrangement, plan, or design, etc., of sth. So, are date, time, currency, and percentage formats different designs/visuals of numerical data? Are these (currency symbols, percentages, dates, time stamps) really just visuals?

In a sense format is a convention to represent different types of data, not necessarily numerical in nature.

In Microsoft Excel the data is stored in some sort of data type like a string, int, double, etc. The format then takes care of representing the information.

Format is data's metadata which stores the options which will enhance the representation of the data. Meaning that a variable that is stored as this number `45086` will be represented as `09-08-2023`, `09/08/2023`, `2023_08_09` and so on.

It also could be said that it applies to even the smallest piece of information, for example `€ 1.50` and `1.50EURO`. The first I would find in a store for the price of something in a format with big letters to draw you attention, the second I would find in a csv document to feed to a database. Same DATA both with different purposes.

In the end, IMO, is a convention to represent data in an specific context.

Comment: How is number formatting different from cell formatting, which includes commands like bold, italic, alignment, text wrapping, etc., if we go with the definition of formatting as a tool used for representing something conventionally?

Answer (score 0):

Data formatting refers to the process of changing the visual representation of data in a spreadsheet without altering its actual values.

Data formatting does not alter the actual values or calculations in your spreadsheet. It only changes how the data is displayed. This means you can apply formatting without affecting any formulas or calculations.

Find few examples in the below picture. For the data next to 1, I am using the default excel values for data formatting. At the data next to 2, I used data formatting, as creating borders, highlighting the header and making it bold and a little bigger, changing the number format in currency at salary column (both salary values in table 1 and table 2 are the same, but I used formatting in the table 2 to show it as $ despite the fact that the actual value in the cell is only the dull number)
[Sample of data formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKjSN.png)

Comment: My take away is that data formatting is so humans can better understand what is being presented. Machines don't care they'll take a bunch of items separated by commas and for the most part know what to do with it.

Comment: @Arbri Sir, can you define just format for me, not data or cell formatting, but just formatting? I have read countless definitions and it goes like this: Format means the general arrangement, plan, or design, etc., of sth. So, are date, time, currency, and percentage formats different designs/visuals of numerical data? Are these (currency symbols, percentages, dates, time stamps) merely just visuals?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there are two distinct types of formatting (in the disambiguated sense) in Excel: **typographical** (or visual) formatting, and **datatype** formatting.

In the former, there is no change being made to the cell values, and the formatting is purely to achieve some visual or aesthetic enhancement or accent upon output.  Examples of this would be changes made to typographical fonts styles and sizes, colors, borders, placement/alignment, etc.  Note that there are still instances where the represented data might be intentionally altered as to change it's perceptibility, e.g., hiding cells, rendering cells invisible typographically, using non-humanreadable fonts (e.g., barcode fonts), etc.

In the latter, while the cell values themselves may or may not remain unchanged, the value that is outputted *does* undergo some change (though they may or may not actually be visible/perceivable purely from visual observation).  Examples of this include conversions of datatypes, defining custom data formats (e.g., to add prefixes/suffixes, units of measure (UOM), discrete symbology or arbitrary encoding, etc.), digit precision, number base conversion, etc.

Within Excel itself, the vernacular term formatting can refer to several different interfaces: cell formatting, sheet organization (e.g., sheet naming, tab colors, etc.), sheet protection (e.g., locking cells), cell input validation, datatype formatting, font formatting, style formatting, clipboard value modifications (e.g., paste-special), illustrations, charting, filtering, annotations, thematic effects, page layout and scaling, object depth arrangements, defined naming, page views, and more!

FYI, Bard defines formatting as:

```
...the organization of information according to preset specifications, usually for computer processing. It can also refer to the way a document is laid out on the page, including margins, spacing, font size, presentation, columns, font selection, indentation, and alignment.
Synonyms of format include:  
 - Layout
 - Formation
 - Arrangement
 - Setup
 - Configuration
 - Design
 - Conformation
 - Plan
```

In terms of why standardization isn't universal, I believe it's simply due to the term being too broad to enforce universal logic conventions ubiquitously (though I'm sure that doesn't mean there *haven't* been standards or attempts at defining them).

Comment: Sir, can you define just format for me, not data or cell formatting, but just formatting? I have read countless definitions and it goes like this: Format means the general arrangement, plan, or design, etc., of sth. So, are date, time, currency, and percentage formats different designs/visuals of numerical data? Are these (currency symbols, percentages, dates, time stamps) merely just visuals?

Comment: To me, the disambiguated term "format" is defined as the **presentation** of something (whether it be data, a book, a picture, etc.).  We apply structural and logical conventions in order to make represented object or data more readable, digestible, relatable, or etc.  No, although visual formatting is significant, as I mentioned before structural or logical conventions are not necessarily visual.  It can also apply to backend mechanics (which isn't visible from userspace), as well as abstract objects or concepts, such as language constructs, etc.

Comment: Do you mean when I apply number format to 5 with two decimal places, the actual value, 5, won't change though the outputted value 5.00 has gone from int to a float in presentation? If yes, doesn't that mean when I apply number formatting to a number, say 5, now they become two numbers, 5 and 5.00? One for presentation, 5.00, and one for calculations, the actual value "5"? Correct me if I am wrong. (I'm asking this question from your "post your answer where U said, "while the cell values themselves may or may not remain unchanged, the value that is outputted does undergo some change".

Comment: In Excel, the actual value stored is as a modified float (refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952372/excel-number-entered-vs-number-displayed-vs-number-stored-in-memory)).  In this case, what the user inputs is formatted automaticall before being stored, while what the user inputs is retained as a format, and what is ultimately outputted is also another format (if distinct for both latter values).